# How to read cell data in excel and output to command prompt

Tags: powershell, microsoft-excel

I'm a sys admin and I am trying to learn how to use powershell... I have never done any type of scripting or coding before and I have been teaching myself online by learning from the technet script centre and online forums.

What I am trying to accomplish is to open an excel spreadsheet get information from it (usernames and password) and then output it into the command prompt in powershell. When ever I try to do this I get an Exception calling "InvokeMember" anyway, here is the code I have so far:

```
 
function Invoke([object]$m, [string]$method, $parameters)
{
$m.PSBase.GetType().InvokeMember(
$method, [Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod, $null, $m, $parameters,$ciUS )
}
```

$ciUS = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]'en-US'

$objExcel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $False
$objExcel.DisplayAlerts = $False

$objWorkbook = Invoke $objExcel.Workbooks.Open "C:\PS\User Data.xls"
Write-Host "Numer of worksheets: " $objWorkbook.Sheets.Count

$objWorksheet = $objWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
Write-Host "Worksheet: " $objWorksheet.Name

$Forename = $objWorksheet.Cells.Item(2,1).Text
$Surname = $objWorksheet.Cells.Item(2,2).Text

Write-Host "Forename: " $Forename
Write-Host "Surname: " $Surname

$objExcel.Quit()
If (ps excel) { kill -name excel}

I have read many different posts on forums and articles on how to try and get around the en-US problem but I cannot seem to get around it and hope that someone here can help!

Here is the Exeption problem I mentioned:

```
Exception calling "InvokeMember" with "6" argument(s): "Method 'System.Management.Automation.PSMethod.C:\PS\User Data.x
ls' not found."
At C:\PS\excel.ps1:3 char:33
+ $m.PSBase.GetType().InvokeMember <<<< (
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Numer of worksheets:
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\PS\excel.ps1:18 char:45
+ $objWorksheet = $objWorkbook.Worksheets.Item <<<< (1)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Item:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Worksheet:
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\PS\excel.ps1:21 char:37
+ $Forename = $objWorksheet.Cells.Item <<<< (2,1).Text
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Item:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\PS\excel.ps1:22 char:36
+ $Surname = $objWorksheet.Cells.Item <<<< (2,2).Text
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Item:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Forename:
Surname:

This is the first question I have ever asked, try to be nice! :))

Many Thanks

Max

Comment: I have a feeling this would be a lot more in place at StackOverflow...

Comment: You reckon? I'm not sure if SO users are going to know Power Shell scripting...

Comment: Actually, on second thoughts, I just went through all the code and it looks very similar to interfacing with the Excel ActiveX object (probably because it is), so on this basis, perhaps SO is the better place for it.

Comment: It is **exactly** the way you'd interface with an Excel worksheet in a .NET application; and that's quite to be expected, since PowerShell actually **is** a .NET language...

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, try modifying your code to run against an `xls` file that doesn't have a space in its name. If that works, then you need to escape the space in the file's name in this line:

```
$objWorkbook = Invoke $objExcel.Workbooks.Open "C:\PS\User Data.xls"
```

or perhaps quote the parameter in this one:

```
$m.PSBase.GetType().InvokeMember(
$method, [Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod, $null, $m, $parameters,$ciUS )
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried modifying the code and I have got it kind of working!

Instead of using

`$objWorkbook = Invoke $objExcel.Workbooks.Open "C:\PS\User Data.xls"`

I took away the `Workbooks.Open "C:\PS\User Data.xls"` and have created a variable `$file = "C:\PS\User Data.xls"`

Now I use

`$objWorkbook = Invoke $objExcel.Workbooks Open($File)`

And it nearly works! It now does not throw any errors at me and here is the outcome in cmd

`Numer of worksheets:  3

Worksheet:  List Of Names

Forename:

Surname:`

But for some reason it still doesnt display the $Forename or $Surname

P.S I've also done as you have said Massimo and created a login on stack overflow and asked the question there!

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: What does your excel spreadsheet look like? I've tested it and it works and the spreadsheet should look like this:

Forename,Surname
Max,Ollerenshaw

Also if you can get the user file in csv file, you could use import-csv cmdlet and that might make things easier

Answer (score 1):

Try using .Value2 instead of text. Here is a simple example of how to open an Excel workbook and read a value:

```
$xl = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$wb = $xl.WorkBooks.Open("C:\temp\test.xls")
$ws = $wb.Worksheets.Item(1)
Write-Host $ws.Cells.Item(2,1).Value2
```

Comment: Hey,

I tried that and it didnt work, there are no errors but the cmd prompt doesn't output the name

Max

Comment: Ok, then I would suggest some exploration. At the command line do all the steps up to where you would do the Write-Host. At that point do this: **$ws.Cells.Item(2,1) | fl ***    Then look for your value in the output.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your help...I have fixed the problem! I was using PowerShell V2 CTP2, now I have upgraded to CTP3 this has fixed the language barrier problem and I can now run scripts without worrying about the invoke function and all is fine!

Many Thanks

Max